# Doctrine Deployment on test-environment without console-access

Tags: php, doctrine, zend-framework2

I developed an application with Zend Framework and Doctrine ORM. To test the application on another environment, I tried to install it on a Synology DiskStation. I exported the MySQL-database with phpMyAdmin and imported it to the DiskStation. But Doctrine doesn't detect the scheme either all login-credential are correct. So I tried to create the scheme with ssh-access:

```
DiskStation> ./doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create
.../bin/doctrine-module: Permission denied
```

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/bin/doctrine-module and vendor/bin/doctrine-module executabe. Than it works.