# Doctrine Deployment don t fin pdo_mysql, on Synology with console-access

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, synology

I developed an application with Symfony 2.8 and Doctrine ORM. To test the application on another environment, I tried to install it on a Synology DiskStation. But I think Doctrine doesn't detect `pdo_mysql`:

[image]

I use DSM 6.0.1-7393.

`<?php print_r(PDO::getAvailableDrivers());?>` shows:

```
Array ( [0] => mysql [1] => pgsql [2] => sqlite [3] => dblib )
```

`pdo_mysql` is ok.

I can run to `ip-nas/mySfProject/web/config.php`
I have read on [post about permission vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358460/doctrine-deployment-on-test-environment-without-console-access) 
But i have no repertory /doctrine-module .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It s resolved with :
add ip of the local machine who access to the serveur :
- config.php and app_dev.php
in /YourProject/appWeb/

open DSM,  In the control-panel under Web-Services in the php-settings enable Customize PHP open_basedir, append the paths you wish:
add :

```
:/root:/usr/local/bin:/volume1/@appstore/PHP5.6/usr/local/bin/php56
```

Where i put composer : 
    - /usr/local/bin

Composer instal give the red path : 
    - /volume1/@appstore/PHP5.6/usr/local/bin/php56

```
SynHome> curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
SynHome> mkdir /usr/local/bin/composer/
SynHome> chmod 440 composer.phar
SynHome> mv composer.phar
SynHome> rm -r vendor
SynHome> rm -r bin
SynHome> php56 /usr/local/bin/composer/composer.phar install

SynHome> php56 app/console doctrine:database:create
SynHome> php56 app/console doctrine:schema:update
```

No PDO exception, now the base is full.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was struggling with the same issue fow hours and was finally able to use doctrine again by simply using php56